# AutoHotKey: Odd window sizing behavior on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, autohotkey

I realise this is probably a really obscure problem but hey it's the internet.

I have a 24" portrait monitor, and I wanted vertical snapping. I found an online script, but for most types of windows, setting their size to the exact dimensions of the monitor resolution resulted in them being slightly too small. This occurs with Chrome, Edge and even Notepad. However, the Telegram window behaves as desired.

Debugging the AHK script shows that when Edge is maximised on a 1200x1920 monitor, the size is actually 1216x1896 (vertical is smaller accounting for the start menu, but it's still taller than it should be).

I've double checked windows display scaling settings, and it is definitely set to 100%.

Does anyone know what's going on here?

At the moment I've had to get around it by doing various inspections and assigning the different methods to different hot keys.

```
; dir 0 = top part
; dir 1 = bottom part
; method 0 = funky
; method 1 = exact

ResizeWin(dir = 1, method = 0)
{
    WinGet activeWin, ID, A
    activeMon := GetMonitorIndexFromWindow(activeWin)

    SysGet, MonitorWorkArea, MonitorWorkArea, %activeMon%

    if (method == 0) {
        WinMaximize, A
        WinGetPos, CurWinX, CurWinY, CurWinWidth, CurWinHeight, A
        newWidth := CurWinWidth
        newHeight := CurWinHeight/2
        newLeft := CurWinX

        if (dir == 1)
            newTop := MonitorWorkAreaTop + newHeight + (CurWinY - MonitorWorkAreaTop)
        else
            newTop := MonitorWorkAreaTop
    } else {

        newWidth := MonitorWorkAreaRight - MonitorWorkAreaLeft
        newHeight := (MonitorWorkAreaBottom - MonitorWorkAreaTop)/2
        newLeft := MonitorWorkAreaLeft

        if (dir == 1)
            newTop := MonitorWorkAreaBottom - newHeight
        else
            newTop := MonitorWorkAreaTop    
    }

    WinRestore,A
    WinMove,A,,%newLeft%,%newTop%,%newWidth%,%newHeight%
}

; From http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/69464-how-to-determine-a-window-is-in-which-monitor/
GetMonitorIndexFromWindow(windowHandle)
{
    ; Starts with 1.
    monitorIndex := 1

    VarSetCapacity(monitorInfo, 40)
    NumPut(40, monitorInfo)

    if (monitorHandle := DllCall("MonitorFromWindow", "uint", windowHandle, "uint", 0x2)) 
        && DllCall("GetMonitorInfo", "uint", monitorHandle, "uint", &monitorInfo) 
    {
        monitorLeft   := NumGet(monitorInfo,  4, "Int")
        monitorTop    := NumGet(monitorInfo,  8, "Int")
        monitorRight  := NumGet(monitorInfo, 12, "Int")
        monitorBottom := NumGet(monitorInfo, 16, "Int")
        workLeft      := NumGet(monitorInfo, 20, "Int")
        workTop       := NumGet(monitorInfo, 24, "Int")
        workRight     := NumGet(monitorInfo, 28, "Int")
        workBottom    := NumGet(monitorInfo, 32, "Int")
        isPrimary     := NumGet(monitorInfo, 36, "Int") & 1

        SysGet, monitorCount, MonitorCount

        Loop, %monitorCount%
        {
            SysGet, tempMon, Monitor, %A_Index%

            ; Compare location to determine the monitor index.
            if ((monitorLeft = tempMonLeft) and (monitorTop = tempMonTop)
                and (monitorRight = tempMonRight) and (monitorBottom = tempMonBottom))
            {
                monitorIndex := A_Index
                break
            }
        }
    }

    return %monitorIndex%
}

^#Up::ResizeWin(0)
^#Down::ResizeWin(1)
+^#Up::ResizeWin(0, 1)
+^#Down::ResizeWin(1, 1)
```